# Is it possible to use only english.pickle in NLTK punkt word_tokenize to decrease deployment package size?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, nltk, pickle, tokenize

I created an AWS Lambda function that uses NLTK and other libraries, but the zipped size and uncompressed size of the deployment package have exceeded the respective 50MB and 250MB size limit.

One way I think I can shrink the deployment package size is by removing all the non-English pickle files in the nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt folder, but this gives a loading file error when executing because I believe Python is looking for all the language files.

Is there a way to specify the English language in my `from nltk import word_tokenize` or where I use `word_tokenize()`? And if I could specify a language somewhere, will it still require the other language files?

Comment: What did you install with `nltk.download()`?

Comment: @alvas nltk.download('punkt')